# Que puertos usa Firebase Realtime Database para enviar datos?

Tags: base-de-datos, firebase, react-native, app, networking

Estoy usando Firebase Realtime database para desarrollar una app en Android e iOS usando React Native.

Cuando envío datos desde mi ordenador de desarrollo (que está conectado a la red A) todo funciona bien.

Cree versiones release para beta testing y los móviles todos se conectan a la red B, el problema es que no son capaces de enviar ningún dato, cuando cambian a redes móviles si envían los datos. Uno de los requisitos de la app es que tiene que enviar los datos conectada a la red B. Para el correcto funcionamiento tengo que hablar con el administrador de la red para liberar los puertos necesarios.

Qué puertos son estos? (He intentado un analizador de paquetes en mi móvil pero sólo me dice la url de mi base de datos)

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta... [¿quizá sea esto lo que quieres?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

Comment: red A y red B son redes moviles (Ej. Movistar) o son redes WiFi?

Comment: @NeryOrtez red A y B son WiFi

Answer (score 0):

Intenta liberar el puerto 443 que se usa para HTTPS. Y aplica una regla a las siguientes IPs:
`74.125.0.0/16 35.192.0.0/12`